"Flask and JavaScript Password Generator: Unable to Display Generated Password on Webpage
So im working on a Project for my self to learn flask. I wrote a Password generator who generates a Password  based on the user's input. I wrote a function how sends the user inputs to the generator and then collects the response how gets send in json format. So when i click my button "Generate Password" it should print out the password. To see if the password even gets generated and sent, i put a console.log(data.password) so it prints it out in the console. 
So you can see the password gets generated but somehow i cant print it out on my Webpage. Can someone help me and tell my what the Problem is?
app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_from_directory, jsonify
import random
import string
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox

app = Flask(__name__)

password_label = None

def generate_password(length, characters):
    password = ''.join(random.choices(characters, k=length))
    return password

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/generate', methods=['POST'])
def generate():
    
    try:
        length = int(request.form.get('length'))
        characters = request.form.get('characters')
        
        if characters == 'letters':
            characters = string.ascii_letters
        elif characters == 'letters_digits':
            characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
        elif characters == 'all':
            characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
        
        password = generate_password(length, characters)
        
        return jsonify(password=password)
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify(error=str(e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


and here is my "index.html":
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Password Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Password Generator</h1>
    
    <form action="/generate" method="POST" id="password-form">
        <label for="length">Password Length:</label>
        <input type="number" id="length" name="length" required><br><br>
        
        <label for="characters">Character Set:</label>
        <select id="characters" name="characters">
            <option value="letters">Letters</option>
            <option value="letters_digits">Letters and Digits</option>
            <option value="all">All Characters</option>
        </select><br><br>
        
        <input type="button" value="Generate Password" onclick="generatePassword()">
        
    </form>
  
    <br>
    <br>
        
    <div>
        {% if password %}
        <h2>Your generated password:</h2>
        <p id="generated-password" type="text" value="..."> {{ password }}</p>
{% endif %}
        
    </div>


    <script>
        function generatePassword() {
            const length = document.getElementById('length').value;
            const characters = document.getElementById('characters').value;
            
            const form = document.getElementById('password-form');

            const formData = new FormData(form);
            formData.append('length', length);
            formData.append('characters', characters);

            
            fetch('/generate', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData

            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data.password);  // Debugging
                document.getElementById('generated-password').innerText = data.password;


            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>


My goal is to print out the password on the Webpage.

i don't think you're passing password to your jinja template, making you miss the if block (because there is no password) and not rendering a field with id generate-password. Later trying to get an element with that id returns null in your javascript, on which you try to access InnerText causing your error.
{% if password %}
    <h2>Your generated password:</h2>
    <p id="generated-password" type="text" value="..."> {{ password }}</p>
{% endif %}

you should either add an else block in this if block like this
{% if password %}
    <h2>Your generated password:</h2>
    <p id="generated-password" type="text" value="..."> {{ password }}</p>
{% else %}
    <!--create the fields empty if no password was generated-->
    <h2>Your generated password:</h2>
    <p id="generated-password" type="text" value="..."></p>
{% endif %}

or pass the value of the generated password via your render_template function like this
return render_template('index.html',password=generate_password(8,string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation))

edits can be made as follows
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Password Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Password Generator</h1>
    <!--https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/flashing/-->
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
            <ul class=flashes>
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <li>{{ message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
             </ul>
        {% endif %}
     {% endwith %}
    <form action="/generate" method="POST" id="password-form">
        <label for="length">Password Length:</label>
        <input type="number" id="length" name="length" required><br><br>
        
        <label for="characters">Character Set:</label>
        <select id="characters" name="characters">
            <option value="letters" selected>Letters</option>
            <option value="letters_digits">Letters and Digits</option>
            <option value="all">All Characters</option>
        </select><br><br>
        
        <input type="submit" value="Generate Password">
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>
        {% if password %}
            <h2>Your generated password:</h2>
            <p id="generated-password" type="text" value="..."> {{ password }}</p>
        {% endif %}
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>

and your python code like
from flask import flash
@app.route('/generate', methods=['POST'])
def generate():
    try:
        length = int(request.form.get('length'))
        characters = request.form.get('characters')
        
        if characters == 'letters':
            characters = string.ascii_letters
        elif characters == 'letters_digits':
            characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
        elif characters == 'all':
            characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
        
        password = generate_password(length, characters)
        
        return render_template("index.html",password=password)
    except Exception as e:
        flash(str(e))
        return render_template("index.html")

the second solution generates a default value, though considering you want the user to fill in a form first i'd like to point you to the first method
to be honest though, you don't need the if block here

So i used the second solution with the else block and it works. But can you tell my why it wasn't working before? Cause it isn't a big difference?

i updated it at the top of the answer "making you miss the if block and not rendering a field with id generate-password later trying to request an element with that id returns null in your javascript, on which you try to access InnerText"

Can you tell me what you've changed in the index.html?

i removed the javascript, directly submit the form (type="button" => type="submit") though this requires the post endpoint to return html instead of json (the render template part), and flash message when an error occurs
